# How to refresh fragment by clicking on button

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, buttonclick, android-fragment-manager, supportfragmentmanager

I want to refresh my fragment by clicking on its button. How to do it?
I try to do it like this but old version of fragment appears on the top of the screen (picture is attached):

```
binding.checkAnswersButton.setOnClickListener {
           requireFragmentManager().beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.quizFragment, QuizFragment())
                    .commit()
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will refresh the fragment :

```
    val ft = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit()
```